# What is the wrong in my code because I am not getting any data back

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am writing a web scraper code in python so I can get the weather data from  [this page](https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/us/tx/austin/KAUS). After running the code there is no data or any output shown:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = "https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/us/tx/austin/KAUS/date/2000-1"

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html")

print(soup)
```

This is my code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.